# Allow multiple categories with the same name with a nested set structure

Tags: mysql, nested-sets

Based on http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/, I've changed my category hierarchy to use left and right values. This works great, except for when two categories have the same name.

```
CREATE TABLE `nested_category` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lft` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rgt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=28 ;

INSERT INTO `nested_category` VALUES(2, 'Reviews', 3, 20);
INSERT INTO `nested_category` VALUES(6, 'Music2', 24, 25);
INSERT INTO `nested_category` VALUES(18, 'Culture', 2, 21);
INSERT INTO `nested_category` VALUES(19, 'Music', 18, 19);
```

And then:

```
SELECT node.name, (
COUNT( parent.name ) -1
) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node, nested_category AS parent
WHERE node.lft
BETWEEN parent.lft
AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY node.name
ORDER BY node.lft
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

... gives:

```
name  depth 
Culture 0
Reviews 1
Music   2
Music2  0
```

... which is perfect. But, if I change "music2" to "music", I get:

```
name  depth 
Culture 0
Reviews 1
Music   3
```

Any ideas as to how I can keep the nesting depth correct, but allow multiple categories with the same name?

Comment: Can't you just add the id to the result and group by?

Comment: lol, one of those <duh> moments. If it solves your problem, I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the id to the result and `GROUP BY` to retain the uniqueness of your select.

```
SELECT node.name, id, (
COUNT( parent.name ) -1
) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node, nested_category AS parent
WHERE node.lft
BETWEEN parent.lft
AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY node.name, id
ORDER BY node.lft
LIMIT 0 , 30
```